# Return 1 in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, return

Normally, in objective-c returning 0 is normal
but what does it mean when I write code like this?

```
if(written){
        NSLog(@"write failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return 1;
    };
```

what does return 1 means?
here is the whole code
    // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:&error];

    if(!data){
        NSLog(@"fetch failed:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return 1;
    }

    NSLog(@"The file is %lu bytes", (unsigned long)[data length]);

    BOOL written = [data writeToFile:@"/tmp/google.png" options:0 error:&error];

    if(written){
        NSLog(@"write failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return 1;
    }

    NSLog(@"Success");

}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you call the method writeToFile: options: error: on your data object
This method returns YES if it has succeeded or NO if it has not not.
The following lines :

```
if(written){
    NSLog(@"write failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return 1;
}
```

seems to be intended as a return for error. Meaning, if your method succeeded it will return 1,  else it will return 0. So I suggest changing written to !written giving :

```
if(!written){
    NSLog(@"write failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return 1;
}
```

Then is written is NO because the writeToFile method failed, you'll get a return value of 1 with a Log message telling you the description of your error given by [error localizedDescription]

That is helpful because you can then determine whether the write was successful or not.
You also could have several different values of return depending on the error produced to return a specific error code each time.

Comment: So was it necessary to put return 1 or can i do it differently but not adding return 1 at all?

Comment: If you remove the return 1 you won't be able to know if the writeToFile method succeeded. Each time you execute it your method would return 0 meaning that it succeeded even it didn't. So I would suggest letting the return 1 in place !

Comment: But I did what the NSLog to tell me the write fail. What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here

Comment: What I meant is if the fetch fail my code will print something like "Fetch Failed" using NSLog. I don't really need return 1 right?

Comment: Only you can read the console, if you want your program to know if your fetch succeeded, you need to return something.
For example if you want an message to appear to inform the user that the fetch was successful or if you want to tell your program that it should move on to the next step, you need a way to tell if it has been successful. You can do it like that :

if (myMethodResult == 0) {
    // Do the next step
} else {
   // Inform user that it has failed
}

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't mean anything in this case... it means what you mean it to mean. In a lot of library calls a failure will be -1 or 0, other calls 0 is success and non-zero is an error... but without context your question isn't answerable.

Comment: do you want to see the whole code it is not that long.

Comment: based on the log messages 0 is success and 1 is failure.